# flattening list comprehension, two list comprehensions at once

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Why does this flattens the list `L`?

```
[item for sublist in L for item in sublist]
```

That doesn't make any intuitive sense to me, I don't know how I can read it so that it does. How am I meant to parse this nested list comprehension?

I would totally expect this to work instead:

```
[item for item in sublist for sublist in L]
```

But it counterintuitively doesn't (sublist is undefined).

How is `[item for sublist in L for item in sublist]` parsed?

Comment: List comprehension loop order works the opposite direction from what you expect.

Comment: as @user2357112supportsMonica states, think of it this way, the loop order is the same as it would be in a nested for-loop.

Comment: Please read https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested comprehensions are the same order as you would write a nested for-loop:

```
result = []
for sublist in L:
    for item in sublist:
        result.append(item)
```

I usually format my comprehensions to help remind future me:

```
result = [item
          for sublist in L
          for item in sublist]
```

Comment: Thanks for such a clear explanation. I understand how to read them now. It still doesn't make sense to me though. Is there a way to have this become intuitive?

Comment: One intuition is that each of the names you use has to exist for the Python interpreter to understand the expression. So, `sublist` has to be defined before you can say `for item in sublist`.

Comment: Thanks. It's still such nonsense to me though. Like that one answer in the linked duplicate, "of all the gin joints in all the towns in all the world" == `[ginjoint for town in world for ginjoint in town]`. That's hilarious to me. I guess I will just have to learn this. Your suggestion of using indentation and formatting is good, thanks.